# Parallel development on Linux

Tags: untagged

I am Java developer on Windows environment and now I want to start development on Linux environment. I know that Linux is a multi-users platform. So my question is, can more than one developers work on same Linux?

For example - I have a Linux server and two Windows OS machine. Both two windows machine access the Linux machine via VNC. There is a project (web application) in the Linux server and two eclipse IDE. Now both users checkout same project from own machine and start development. Is it possible? If 'Yes', then how? and I 'No', then is there any other way for parallel development?

Regards,
Amit

Comment: This question is simply off topic.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it's possible, but** you should make sure, that both users have different working directories, from which they commit their changes to a central code repository. Otherwise, multi-user or not, you'll overwrite each others' changes.

You should consider Subversion for that, if you don't already have a version control system.

But **programming over VNC is not that pleasant**. I have much better experience with this setup:

1. Two Windows developer machines, running Linux with VirtualBox in Seamless Mode.
2. The changes are committed to a central Linux server running Subversion.

It also has the advantage, that one can always work, even if the server temporarily cannot be reached.

Comment: Here you are talking about different working directories for both users. For our development, I did as follows - 

Both users created different workspace for eclipse. And both import the existing project from "/var/www/html" (DocumentRoot path for Apache). Till that no problems, but when one user run the project from eclipse then he can but other user cann't run that project.

Thus here I was create two different workspace for both users and project's source was same. But at the time, both users cann't run the project.

Comment: Yes, that's what I really meant with different working directories: You cannot work on the same source, and even if you could, you shouldn't. You'll run into all kinds of problems, starting with concurrent modifications of the same file and destroying the local file history. (Not that you should depend on it...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. I would also recommend a version control system and separate user accounts.

But instead of VNC I would highly recommend [No Machine (NX)](http://www.nomachine.com/)
This will allow people to simultaneously use the system without seeing the same thing on the screen (although that is available also). Also, it will be **much** more responsive than VNC. I would say that NX to a computer a mile away is about as responsive as VNC on a LAN. You should also look into using FreeNX (GPL) rather than the paid version.

Comment: Just to clarify: "simultaneously use the system without seeing the same thing on the screen" is possible with VNC as well, no difference in that point. NX *is* significanter faster than VNC over slow links, though.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I guess it is just an issue of default settings.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the other answers, Linux was meant as a multi-user from day one, so there's no problem with multiple users working simultaneously. Just give every user their own login account, then they'll automatically get their own home directory, and can work independently. Both VNC and NX will work for remote access. You can even use Linux as an RPD (Remote desktop protocol) server, if you want to access it using Windows's built-in RDP client (no experience with that though).

One point to note: You write

> but when one user run the project from eclipse then he can but other user cann't run that project

Could you post the exact error message? "other user cann't run" isn't terribly helpful.

I suspect you are using a fixed TCP port for your webb application. While most resources on a Linux system exist per user, TCP ports are a global resource, so two users cannot use the same port simultaneously. You will simply have to make a rule so that every dev has their own port (one might use 9000, the next 9001, etc.). Then each can run the webapp on their own port (by setting it in the app server) without interference from others.

Note that running on a different port should make no difference whatsoever to a web app. While HTTP normally usees port 80, it will work over any port. Just access it as http://localhost:9000 (for port 9000) etc.